# The math department of a college has 20 faculty members, of whom 5 are women and 15 are men...

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Continued question: "A curriculum committee of 4 faculty members is to be selected. How many ways are there to select the committee that has more women than men?"

Possible Ways:

---

M M M M

F F F F

F F M M

F F F M

M M M F

Is it suppose to be 2/5?

Comment: it's asking for the number of ways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more women than men, then there are either 3 women, 1 man or there are 4 women, 0 men.

If there are 3 women, 1 man, then there are a total of $\dbinom{5}{3} \times \dbinom{15}{1} = 150$ ways of doing it.

If there are 4 women, 0 men, then there are a total of $\dbinom{5}{4} \times \dbinom{15}{0} = 5$ ways of doing it.

Therefore, there are a total of $\boxed{155}$ ways of doing it.

Comment: there are 5 women total lol

Comment: @SakethMalyala thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Also it asks for the number of ways, not a probability!

You are correct in that you need $3$ or $4$ women.

For the case where there are $3$ women and $1$ man:

You can select the woman in $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways and the man in $15$ ways, for a total of $150$ ways.

For the committee of $4$ women, you can select the $4$ women in $\binom{5}{4}=5$ ways.

This makes a total of $\boxed{155}$ ways to choose a committee of mostly women.